# Is Sarah G.Lato actually the creator?

Tags: character-motivation, amazing-world-of-gumball

Lately, I have been thinking about the role of the character Sarah G.Lato in the Amazing World of Gumball show and I have begun wondering what her actual intended power is.

Let me explain what I mean. Sarah seems to linger on constant 4th wall breaking, but in a way she seems also to imply she has some form of "control" on the show itself, basically making her AWOG version of Haruhi Suzumiya.

Some random examples of this weird behavior:

- she was meant to be a replacement for Molly after she got removed. Nothing strange, if the show didn't point out that "in-world" Molly disappearance was caused by the world itself considering her **an error** and banishing her to an alternate dimension of cancelled content. Basically, as far as the plot goes Sarah G.Lato came to the world to replace something that the world considered an error.
- she is the greatest fan of Gumball/Darwin. Which are the protagonist of the shown. And yes, she knows that and actually points out their roles in the episode "The Test"
- during "The Sweaters" episode she is able to keep popping in front of Gumball and Darwin as they try to avoid her, showing Pinkie level disregard for space and time rules. In a single scene there are also two Sarah on the screen. I don't know if anyone did that in the show.
- she whistles the show ending theme during an episode.
- even if they are doing this supposedly out of friendship, it is worth nothing to notice that Gumball and Darwin end up reacting the fan-fic she wrote during an episode.
- she is able to trigger a "episode end" scene in multiple occasions
- she shares her name with the series' executive producer, Sarah Fell.

  But what really made me thinking is a single line during "The Test" episode.

  > Sarah: No! He's ruining the continuity! **My continuity!**

she calls that... **MY** continuity.

So, now I am asking.
Is there any reference that actually confirms Sarah G.Lato to be a sort of Sarah Fell avatar?

Comment: It seems to be intended that way, but I've looked around and can't find any evidence that actually confirms it. That's the way a lot of the "is this character based off of another character" and "Is this character supposed to be ------" I don't know if this should be an answer, but it is definitely intended, with no concrete confirmation however

Comment: @Hyperdriveenthusiast That is what I meant. I am basically searching for any reference material confirming that she is intended to be an avatar for Sarah Fell. Maybe some interview or anything similar ^_^

Comment: Well, I've been looking for a while and haven't found any concrete reference